# How to keep opacity at the first half of a div while linear transitioning?

Tags: html, css

I want to keep part of the opacity on the div, I mean as the transitioning is progressing the first part of the div to be with the initial opacity and the end of the div with the final color.

This is what i have so far:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ffd42b;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s; /* Safari */
  opacity: 0.1;
  transition: all 15s linear 0.2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}

div:hover {
  width: 300px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Not using `opacity` no. You might be able to animate a gradient over the top but I don't think this will do what you want it too.

Comment: your question is not quite clear... Are you looking for a transition filling the background ? any particular example? you must have seen this somewhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider [`mask`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask) to do this. The idea is to define two masks: one will remain fixed and will define the initial opacity that should not change and the other will get animated from bottom to top to simulate the opacity transition of the right part.

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/103/300/100);
  -webkit-mask:
    linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.3),rgba(0,0,0,0.3)) 0 0       /100px 100% no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,1)  ,rgba(0,0,0,0)  ) 100px 100%/100%  600% no-repeat;
   mask:
    linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.3),rgba(0,0,0,0.3)) 0 0       /100px 100% no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,1)  ,rgba(0,0,0,0)  ) 100px 100%/100%  600% no-repeat;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

.box:hover {
  width: 300px;
  -webkit-mask-position:0 0,100px 0%;
  mask-position:0 0,100px 0%;
}

body {
 background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gradient CSS to do it, I put a little bit of color in the transparence to you see more clearly the effect, but if you want 100% of tranparence just put zero in the last value of the rgba in the linear-gradient like this

```
 background-image: linear-gradient( rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.0), red);
```

and if you want to change the side of the transparence just invert the values

```
 background-image: linear-gradient(red, rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.0));
```

```css
main {  max-width:1000px; min-height:100vh; 
 background: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/06/30/09/31/background-image-3507320_960_720.jpg); 
  background-size:100%;
}
 #half-color{ border:3px solid #333; 
   background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(55, 66, 55, 0.5), red);
   min-height: 200px; min-width: 300px; }
```

```html
<main>
<div id='half-color'>
</div>
</main>
```